# Deploy contract through gnosis transaction-builder

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to deploy a smart-contract using Gnosis-safe's Transaction Builder by setting an empty ABI `[]`, the target address to the zero address (`0x00...0`), value to 0 and passing the custom hex data as the contract's bytecode, generated through hardhat. The UI goes through but gets stuck after I sign the transaction so I'm wondering if this is possible at all. Thank you

Images:
[image: transaction]
[image: stuck after signing]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to deploy a contract via a Safe you need to use a deployment proxy.

In the Safe repository you can find the [CreateCall](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/CreateCall.sol) for this, but there are also community based contract for this (e.g. https://github.com/Arachnid/deterministic-deployment-proxy).

Important to note is that when you use these deployment proxies is that the `msg.sender` in your deployed contract will be the proxy and not your Safe.

If you want that `msg.sender` is your Safe then you have to use a `delegatecall` when creating the Safe transaction (which is not possible via the transaction builder).

If you use hardhat you can try this library: https://github.com/rmeissner/hardhat-safe-deployer

Note: Deploying a contract by only specifying the data for a transaction is something specific to EoAs and will not work for smart contracts.